# AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'has_premissions`

Tags: python, discord.py

im trying to make mute command but it shows this error "Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 23, in 
@commands.has_premissions(kick_member=True)
AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'has_premissions'" the code:

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions, is_owner
import json

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/')
status=discord.Status.idle

@client.command()
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason=None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"{member} was banned by {ctx.author.name} for reason {reason}")

    
@client.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member,reason=None):
  await member.kick(reason=reason)
  await ctx.send(f"{member} was kicked by {ctx.author.name} for reason {reason}")

@client.command(aliases=['m'])
@commands.has_premissions(kick_member=True)
async def mute(ctx,member : discord.Member):
  muted_role = ctx.guild.get_role(905765835791036477)
  
@client.event
async def on_ready():
 print('we have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


my_secret = os.environ['Token']

client.run(my_secret)
```

Comment: Probably a typo: has_premissions vs has_permissions

Answer (score 1):

- You've written "p`er`missions" as "p`re`missions";
- You've written "kick_member`s`" as "kick_member".

### Picture:

[image]

### Links:

- [`discord.Permissions.kick_members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Permissions.kick_members)
- [`@commands.has_permissions()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has_perms#discord.ext.commands.has_permissions)

#### Suggestion

I suggest you to add the `has_permissions` check to the kick and ban commands too…

Answer (score 0):

You've written `has_premissions`, not `has_permissions`, and the correct syntax seems to be `kick_members`, not `kick_member`, as per https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Permissions

Comment: yeah i figured that out but it still shows this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 23, in <module>
    @commands.has_permissions(kick_member=True)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1779, in has_permissions
    raise TypeError('Invalid permission(s): %s' % (', '.join(invalid)))
TypeError: Invalid permission(s): kick_member

Comment: Can you update your code with the correct spelling and full error message then so that others can see what the issue is

Comment: Try `kick_members` instead of `kick_member`